# JsonProperty format custom date

Tags: .net, json, datetime, json.net

The date returned after using the Json.deserialize is in this format: 2017-10-11T00:00:00Z. This is how I am receiving the date from the XML:

```
[JsonProperty("Date")]
public DateTime CustomDate { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("Name")]
public string name { get; set; }
```

So CustomDate returns "2017-10-04T00:00:00Z". I want CustomDate to return 10/11/2017. How can this be achieved? I have already tried using JsonConverter:

```
class CustomDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public CustomDateTimeConverter()
    {
        base.DateTimeFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    }
}
```

Calling the function() like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
[JsonProperty("Date")]
public DateTime CustomDate { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("Name")]
public string name { get; set; }
```

After doing this I get an error saying "string was not recognized as a valid datetime". **How can I format this string to display: 10/11/2017?**

Comment: Try changing the type of your `CustomDate` property from `string` to `DateTime`.

Comment: Yes, tried that. It did not work.

Comment: @netchi try this `string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObjectHere,
    new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy" });`

Comment: You asked, *How can I format this string to display: 10/11/2017?* -- but your custom `DateTimeFormat` is `"MM-dd-yyyy"` which will produce `"10-11-2017"`.  If you really want `"10/11/2017"` then surely your `DateTimeString` must needs be something like `"MM/dd/yyyy"`?

Comment: @dbc corrected my question. I want to extract 10 11 2017 now it doesn't matter what format it is in. It could be 10-11-2017 or 10/11/2017!

Comment: @netchi - Can you provide a [mcve] for your problem?  I tried applying your converter as shown in your question and `"Date": "10/11/2017"` is generated as JSON output.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/mG2ukx for a demo.

Comment: @dbc Thanks, your solution worked. I was not calling it in a correct way.